# pygame draw.rect not working with surface.fill

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Hi I've looked at multiple posts and can't see my answer. I'm building a simple snake game and when I loop through `draw.rect` it doesn't work in conjunction with surface.fill.

It seems like it doesn't matter where I put the `flip()`/`update()` command, please help!

```
import pygame
from pygame import Color

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
gs = 20
tail = 5
trail = []
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 250)
sx = sy = 15
vx = vy = 0
block = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 20, 20)

while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            trail.append({"x": sx, "y": sy})
            print(trail)
            while len(trail) > tail:
                trail.pop(0)
            surface.fill(Color("black"))
            for t in trail:
                print(t)
                pygame.draw.rect(
                    surface, Color("green"), (sx * gs, sy * gs, gs - 1, gs - 1)
                )
                pygame.display.update()

            sx += vx
            sy += vy

        if sx > gs - 1:
            sx = 0
        if sx < 0:
            sx = gs - 1
        if sy > gs - 1:
            sy = 0
        if sy < 0:
            sy = gs - 1

        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == 273 and vy != 1:
                vx, vy = 0, -1
            if e.key == 274 and vy != -1:
                vx, vy = 0, 1
            if e.key == 275 and vx != -1:
                vx, vy = 1, 0
            if e.key == 276 and vx != 1:
                vx, vy = -1, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You keep drawing same thing, rectangle at (sx * gs, sy * gs, gs - 1, gs - 1), not using x and y values inside trail. Draw rect input should be:

```
surface, Color("green"), (t["x"] * gs, t["y"] * gs, gs - 1, gs - 1)
```